# python locale - wrong decimal_point for german (de_DE) settings

Tags: python-2.7, locale, decimal-point

I'm getting wrong decimal separator on this locale. 
short code example:

```
import locale
print locale.getdefaultlocale()[0]
print "decimal_point:", locale.localeconv()["decimal_point"]
print (float(1)/float(2))
```

the results are:

```
de_DE
decimal_point: .
0.5
```

(decimal separator is dot instead of comma).
Python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')`. As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/locale.html#locale.getdefaultlocale) point out:

> According to POSIX, a program which has not called 
>   `setlocale(LC_ALL, '')`
>   runs using the portable `'C'` locale. Calling `setlocale(LC_ALL, '')`
>   lets it use the default locale as defined by the **LANG** variable. Since
>   we do not want to interfere with the current locale setting we thus
>   emulate the behavior in the way described above.

Comment: Tnx a lot, but it solved only half of the problem.  the decimal_point got the comma, but yet the number is displayed as 0.5 (zero dot five) instead of 0,5 (zero comma five).

Comment: Yes, because `str()` is "locale-unaware" as PEP 331 put it. To get the correct numeric format, you have to use the format functions in the `locale` module.

Comment: Tnx again,  I do not like it, but looks like this is the "pythonic" way :-)