# Python detect system default decimal separator character (Pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In my software user can load different types of a dataset using Pandas. if the software was installed on windows with English locale where the decimal separator symbol is dot (.) I will pass this char to for example `read_csv` function. like:

```
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", decimal='.')
```

but it can also be installed on, for example, German locale PC where the decimal separator is the comma (,). I can get the current local using:

```
import locale
locale.getdefaultlocale()
```

but it's also possible that in german local the separator is the dot (.). Now the question is how can I explicitly know what is the decimal separator character in python so that I can parse the dataset correctly?

Answer (score 3):

I am so stupid. it was right in the documentation

```
locale.localeconv()["decimal_point"]
```

Comment: this is not correct! I am running Serbian Latin (with ,) but the decimal_point is returning .

Comment: @DejanDozet same is true for German Latin, returns '.' instead of ','
I checked the system settings of windows for my selected region, there the ',' is set as decimal separator

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the locale first.

```
import locale

print(locale.getlocale())
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
print(locale.localeconv())
```

Output for german region setting is then

```
('de_DE', 'cp1252')
{'int_curr_symbol': 'EUR', 'currency_symbol': '€', 'mon_decimal_point': ',', 'mon_thousands_sep': '.', 'mon_grouping': [3, 0], 'positive_sign': '', 'negative_sign': '-', 'int_frac_digits': 2, 'frac_digits': 2, 'p_cs_precedes': 0, 'p_sep_by_space': 1, 'n_cs_precedes': 0, 'n_sep_by_space': 1, 'p_sign_posn': 1, 'n_sign_posn': 1, 'decimal_point': ',', 'thousands_sep': '.', 'grouping': [3, 0]}
```

Be aware that strings need special handling then, see this question about [Python locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500053/python-locale-wrong-decimal-point-for-german-de-de-settings).